# Next/Previous button throws error

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, undefined, multidimensional-array

I keep getting the following error when I try to insert values by clicking the Next button on values that are already entered in.

> Unable to get the value of the property '0': object is null or undefined.

I believe the error is happening at the last value in the array. I indicated the line below with a comment in the code. I want it to get the next value in the array but there isn't one created yet (it gets the next value just fine if the next value is not the last one in the array).

I think that is the reason it's throwing an object `null`. However, I can't seem to check for the `null`/`undefined` and set it using statements such as `result[count+1][0] == undefined` because it doesn't work! It always throws an error no matter what I do.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Test case:

1. Insert a value in text box 1 and text box 2
2. Click Next
3. Click Previous (in order to edit the values inserted above)
4. Change the values in the text boxes to something else
5. Click Next -- error happens

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var result = new Array();
var count = 0;

var input1 = new Array();
var input2 = new Array();

function move(direction) {

if(direction == 'next') 
{
    var rate1 = [document.getElementById("txt1").value];
    var rate2 = [document.getElementById("txt2").value];


        if (result.length == count){

            if (rate1 == '' || rate2 == '') {
                alert('you need to put in a value');
            }
            else {
                result.push([[rate1], [rate2]]);
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
                count++;
            }
        }
        else {          
            try{

            (result[count][0]) = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            (result[count][1]) = document.getElementById("txt2").value;

            document.getElementById("txt1").value = result[count++][0]; //error happening here. trying to show next value but there isn't one created yet. 
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = result[count++][1];

            document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
            }
            catch(err) {
            alert(err.description);
            }           
            count++;

        }   
}

if (direction == 'prev') 
{
    if(count <= 0)
    {
        alert("no more elements");
    }
    else 
    {
        var prev_val1 = (result[count - 1][0]);
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = prev_val1;

        var prev_val2 = (result[count - 1][1]);
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = prev_val2;
        count--;               
    }
}
document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
}

</script>
<li>text 1</li>
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<br>
<li>text 2</li>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="next" onclick="move('next')" />
<input type="button" id="btnprevious" value="previous" onclick="move('prev')" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtresult"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check like this:

```
if (typeof result[count++] === "undefined") { /* do or do not */ };
```

Right before:

```
document.getElementById("txt1").value = result[count++][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function move(direction) {

if(direction == 'next') 
{
    var rate1 = [document.getElementById("txt1").value];
    var rate2 = [document.getElementById("txt2").value];


        if (result.length == count){

            if (rate1 == '' || rate2 == '') {
                alert('you need to put in a value');
            }
            else {
                result.push([[rate1], [rate2]]);
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
                count++;
            }
        }
        else {          
            try{

            (result[count][0]) = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            (result[count][1]) = document.getElementById("txt2").value;

            if( result[ ++count ] )  // this checks for undefined 
            {
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = result[count][0]; //error happening here. trying to show next value but there isn't one created yet. 
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = result[count][1];
            }
            else            
            {
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';         
                count--;  // decrement counter 
            }
            }catch(err) {
            alert(err.description);
            }           
            count++;

        }   
}

if (direction == 'prev') 
{
    if(count <= 0)
    {
        alert("no more elements");
    }
    else 
    {
        var prev_val1 = (result[count - 1][0]);
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = prev_val1;

        var prev_val2 = (result[count - 1][1]);
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = prev_val2;
        count--;               
    }
}
document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you do count++  in these 2 lines?

```
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = result[count++][0]; //error happening here. trying to show next value but there isn't one created yet. 
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = result[count++][1];
```

seems like interpreter first increment the count and then try to get item of result which is undefined...

as i undestand pressing previous must "set cursor" to previous vaues so you can change previously entered values...  in this case you shouldn't increment counter in these lines.. just remove ++

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant to write result[count+1][0], not count++....The above count++ was something I was messing around with earlier...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you embedded the arrays three deep.  I cleaned up some of the code and made the names more understandable (at least to me).

Regardless, when you were on the last value in the array, count++ didn't exist.  Also, don't use count++ as this will increment your count var.  Don't use ++ to simplify unless you truly know what you're doing and want to increment.  Also, tricky shortcuts will confuse people trying to read your code, so try to be as explicit as possible.  (There are exceptions to this statement, as in, you don't need to write for a person who has never coded before)

Here is working javascript:

```
var result = new Array();
var count = 0;

function move(direction) {
    if(direction == 'next') {
        var box1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value; //why did you wrap these as arrays?
    var box2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value; //

    if (result.length == count){
        if (box1 == '' || box2 == '') {
            alert('you need to put in a value');
        } else {
            result.push([box1, box2]); //why did you wrap individual numbers in arrays?
            document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
        }
    } else {          
        try{
            result[count][0] = document.getElementById("txt1").value;  
            result[count][1] = document.getElementById("txt2").value;

            if(result[count+1]) { // need this because if on last value in the array, count+1 will not exist yet
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = result[count+1][0]; //do not do ++.  this will increment count here.  don't be tricky with ++
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = result[count+1][1]; //because it will confuse others and lead to off by 1 errors
            } else {
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
            }
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert(err.description);
        }           
    }
    count++;
}

if (direction == 'prev') {
    if(count <= 0){
        alert("no more elements");
    } else {
        var prev_val1 = result[count - 1][0];
        var prev_val2 = result[count - 1][1];

        document.getElementById("txt1").value = prev_val1;
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = prev_val2;
        count--;               
    }
}
document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
}
```